# Error: Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

Error: Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests.
I have an error when deploying contract to rinkeby

```
 provider const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')

 module.exports = async(deployer) => {
    await deployer.deploy(WETH);
    await deployer.deploy(BNB, admin, 100000e18);
    await deployer.deploy(OMG, admin, 100000e18);
    await deployer.deploy(BAT, admin, 100000e18);     
 };
```

Comment: It is no clear which file do you have problems with, is it the migration or the configuration? It is better if you put both here, which version of truffle are you using?

Comment: thx for response, it was an error in the deploy script, i forgot to add the contract, but the error anyway very strange for this case

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) => {
    deployer.deploy(WETH).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(BNB, admin, 100000e18);
    }).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(OMG, admin, 100000e18);
    }).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(BAT, admin, 100000e18);     
    })
 };
```

Comment: thx for response, it didn't help me, but the problem was that i forgot to add the contract reference, but the error anyway very strange for this case